# Wait for response generated by python file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

I have written a website using nodejs and express my problem is that I am using a python script for face recognition.
The problem is that when I am calling this script from nodejs using child-process but it is taking time(10 to 20s depending) for recognition and nodejs is not
waiting for the response sent by the python file if recognition is successfull or not. And this response is necessary for me to show buttons in website for next steps can u give me some directions on this. What should I do to get the desired results or can u guide me how should I signal my website for further process when the recognition is done by python script.
I my question is not clear please tell me I will try to improve it.

#### index.js

```
const express = require("express");
app.get("/recognize/:id/:whom/:what", async (req, res) => {
  const { id, whom, what } = req.params;
  runPython(id, whom, what);
});
```

#### runPython.js

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
let dataFound = undefined;
const runPython = function (id, whom, what) {
  const pythonProcess = spawn("python", ["fr_final.py", id, whom, what]);

  pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    dataFound = data.toString();
    console.log(dataFound);
    // return resolve(resp);
  });
 //this line generate the required response which I want to use for further process
  pythonProcess.on("exit", return dataFound);
};
```

#### open.js

```
const btnRecog = function (btn, lockerid, whom) {
  btn.classList.remove("hidden");

  btn.addEventListener("click", async function () {
    // tell node to call python script for recognition and somehow wait for its response
    const url = `http://localhost:8082/recognize/${lockerid}/${whom}/reco`;
    const resp = await makeRequest(url);
    if (!resp) return;
  });
};

btnRecog(someBtn, LCR1800, banker) //when this is successfull then execute the other line
btnRecog(someOtherBtn, LCR1800, user) // only execute this after above line is done
```

My application is basically a digilocker where face recognition is done first for the banker if it is successfull then only do recognition for user. How should I achieve this. lockerid is basically the id of the locker for which recognition has to be done

Comment: you have to share your code, how you are invoking the python script from nodejs? the python call is a `script` execution or a REST call ?

Answer (score 0):

We'll have to see code to determine how are you invoking the python script and how are you sending the response. But note that Express also has a connection timeout property.

Express will wait for specified time for your code to send response, otherwise it will timeout the response. If you need to wait longer then the default time, try increasing that timeout value, or use a HTTP pooling session.